# How to write the test for Chips (React js) in Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

How to test this code in cypress?

```
<Chips
  id="ChipsId"
  className="chips"
  value={this.state.tags}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  suggestions={this.state.tagGroup}
  fromSuggestionsOnly="true"
/>
```

I tried code are:

```
      cy.find('#ChipsId')
      .type("Freshers")
      .type('{downarrow}')
      .type('{enter}');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `cy.get()` not `cy.find()`. Also, you need to target the actual `<input type="text">` element, or focus it before using `cy.type`.

Try:

```js
cy.get('#ChipsId').click()
.focused().type('{downarrow}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selector is not correct. You can try

```js
cy.get("Chips[id='ChipsId']")
  .type("Freshers")
  .type('{downarrow}')
  .type('{enter}');
```

Also, if possible try to add `data-*` attribute specific just for testing. Read more on this best practice [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements)

If the above doesn't work, I guess the Chips is a higher order component right? Means it contains several other DOM elements. You need to `get` the input element within the Chips element to type into:

```js
cy.get("Chips[id='ChipsId']").within(() => {
  cy.get('input')
    .type("Freshers")
    .type('{downarrow}')
    .type('{enter}');
})
```

I can't test it now, but maybe even `cy.get("Chips[id='ChipsId'] input")` or `cy.find("Chips[id='ChipsId'] input")` could work.